# Bootstrapping CIs for model predictions: bootstrap model parameters or mean difference in model predictions?

Tags: r, regression, bootstrap

I am calculating the average incremental effect of a disease on number of health care visits. To calculate this effect, I am estimating a model for number of visits as a function of the disease (a binary 0/1 variable) and several covariates. I then use this model to make two predictions of number of visits using a simulated data set: one prediction where the disease variable is manipulated to be as if everyone had the disease (disease variable set to 1 for everyone and predictions averaged) and one prediction as if no one had the disease (disease variable set to 0 for everyone and predictions averaged). The difference in the two average predictions is the average incremental effect of the disease that I am interested in. In my experience, this approach is called recycled predictions.

To quantify uncertainty in this estimate, I would like to bootstrap a 95% CI around it. If I estimate the model using my original data (which has a mix of disease == 0 and disease == 1) and then bootstrap just the mean difference, I get the same point estimate but a different SE/95% CI than if I bootstrap the model coefficients using the original data and then take the difference of the predictions from my simulated data. Which approach is correct?

````
library(tidyverse)
library(boot)

# data

disease <- sample(0:1, 75000, replace=TRUE)
age <- sample(18:88, 75000, replace=TRUE)
score <- sample(0:23, 75000, replace=TRUE)
gender <- sample(0:1, 75000, replace=TRUE)
visits <- sample(0:45, 75000, replace=TRUE)
time <- sample(30:3287, 75000, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(cbind(disease, age, score, gender, visits, time))

# create simulated data set for recycled predictions (disease == 0 and disease == 1)

df_disease0 <- mutate(df, disease = ifelse(disease == 1, 0, 0)) 
df_disease1 <- mutate(df, disease = ifelse(disease == 0, 1, 1)) 

# combine simulated data frames

df_sim <- rbind(df_disease0, df_disease1)

### Bootstrap model coefficients

mean_diff_fn_1 <- function(data, i){
boot_data <- data[i, ]
model <- glm(visits ~ disease + age + score + gender + offset(log(time)),
             data = boot_data, family = poisson)
mean_disease0 <- mean(predict(model, newdata = df_sim[df_sim$disease == 0, ], type = "response"))
mean_disease1 <- mean(predict(model, newdata = df_sim[df_sim$disease == 1, ], type = "response"))
mean_diff <- mean_disease1 - mean_disease0
return(mean_diff)
}

boot_obj_1 <- boot(df, mean_diff_fn_1, 500)
print(boot_obj_1)
boot.ci(boot_obj_1, type = "basic")

### Bootstrap mean difference 

# model

model <- glm(visits ~ disease + age + score + gender + offset(log(time)),
             data = df, family = poisson)

# bootstrap

mean_diff_fn_2 <- function(data, i){
boot_data <- data[i, ]
mean_disease0 <- mean(predict(model, newdata = boot_data[boot_data$disease == 0, ], type = "response"))
mean_disease1 <- mean(predict(model, newdata = boot_data[boot_data$disease == 1, ], type = "response"))
mean_diff <- mean_disease1 - mean_disease0
return(mean_diff)
}

boot_obj_2 <- boot(df_sim, mean_diff_fn_2, 500)
print(boot_obj_2)
boot.ci(boot_obj_2, type = "basic")
```
````

Comment: Please explain your model in words.  Offering a block of code is not sufficient.

Comment: The form of the model is not important. My actual model is a negative binomial generalized additive model that takes about two hours to run in the bootstrap, so I simplified it to a poisson GLM without spline terms for the sake of this example.

Comment: That's fine, but it remains unclear exactly what you mean by "model in the bootstrap" as opposed to "predictions of the means;" and in fact the very meaning of "average incremental effect" is obscure, too.  Please don't require your readers to depend entirely on the code to understand those things, because (1) it excludes many readers who otherwise would be highly qualified to answer and (2) it relies heavily on the assumption that the code correctly implements your intentions.

Comment: @whuber edited per your guidance.

Comment: I have also read the threads on CV about prediction intervals vs. confidence intervals, and I am fairly sure that what I want is a confidence interval (because the predictions are not being generated on new data), but if I have misunderstood that, I would like to know.